# Transformar uma string em json

Tags: c#, json

Preciso montar esse json a partir de uma string e passar como parâmetro:

Fiz isso:
`string s = "{\"Matriz\":12, \"Filial\":21}";`

No click do meu botão tenho isso:

```
private void Click_Service(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataService dataService = new DataService();
            string jvalue = "{"\"Matriz\":12, \"Filial\":21"}";
            dataService.PostIndicador(jvalue);
        }
```

e no meu serviço tenho isso:

```
public async Task<string> PostIndicador(string jsonValue)
        {
            string retorno = null;
            //string jvalue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonValue);
            if (NetworkCheck.IsInternet())
            {
                string url_base = $"meu_ip";
                var uri = new Uri(string.Format(url_base));
                using (var client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = uri })
                {
                    var responeMessage =
                    await client.PostAsync("/Service/Service.svc/GetIndicator", new StringContent("jsonValue", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
                    var resultcontent = await responeMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    retorno = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resultcontent)).ToString();
                }                
            }

            return retorno;
        }
```

A questão toda é se `jsonValue` está com o formato correto, pois quando chega nesta linha

```
var responeMessage = await client.PostAsync("/Service/Service.svc/GetIndicator", new StringContent("jsonValue", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

o sistema aborta. Nem entra no `catch`.

Espero que com esse edit eu tenha saído da pergunta original, acho que não já que o objetivo é montar o json corretamente.

Comment: Inclui a sua string

Comment: Por favor, se possível melhore a descrição do seu problema, e também o complemente com o que você já fez, ou erros que estão acontecendo para nos ajudar a te ajudar.

Comment: Em realidade é montar um json com essa saída. Não tenho idéia de como eu faria com a string. Se `string js="Matriz:12,Filial:21`. Não tenho idéia de como seria, razão do post.

Comment: Você tem esses dados como no C#?  O .net tem serializadores de objetos para json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON, que em tradução livre de *Javascript Object Notation* significa *notação de objeto javascript*, é por si só uma representação serializada de um objeto.

Para descrevê-lo como uma string você só precisa formatar a notação usando das regras da sua linguagem escolhida - no caso, C#:

```
string json = "{\"Matriz\": 12, \"Filial\": 21 }";
```

A única diferença é a utilização do código de escape `\"` para indicar aspas duplas.

Comment: Estava fazendo, mas não estava colocando o caracter "\". Mas Não sabia da aspa simples. Nem me passou pela cabeça. Vaçleu OnoSendai. Assim que rodar e der certo, marco sua resposta. E depois eu serializo, como eu faço para gerar o json?